# Getting a div tag over another in fluid grid

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I'm trying to get one div tag over another in a fluid grid page.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like the top blue strip, that you see on facebook front page. It has a blue line spanning across the screen width and facebook logo is somewhere near left corner.

My situation is I'm trying to achieve this via two div tags. One div spanning across the width of the browser and add another div below that and set the `margin-top` to a negative equivalent to the `height` of the first div.

But this way, the second div goes behind the first div which covers the whole width of the browser screen and not visible. Is there a method to get the **second div visible in front of the first div**.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand parts of this without seeing some of the code but I may have an idea to help you.

For CSS, try adding a `z-index` to the divs.

```
#first-div {
    z-index: 100;
}
#second-div {
    z-index: 105;
}
```

This will put the `#second-div` over the `#first-div`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/RB4Ue/), if this is what you want to achieve.

**HTML**

```
<div id="topbar">

  <div class="topbar-wrapper">

    <span class="logo">Your Logo Here</span>

    <input type="text" class="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">

  </div>

</div>

<div class="message">

  <div class="message-wrapper">

    This is a simple message for visitor.

    <span class="close">Close</span>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="content">

  <span>CONTENT</span>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#topbar {
  background: #44619d;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.topbar-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #344d7f;
}
.search {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 1px 0 2px 4px;
  border: 1px solid #344d7f;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
.search:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.message {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff9d7;
  display: block;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #444;
  z-index: 9998;
}
.close {
  float: right;
  margin: -1px 20px 0 0;
  padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
  border: 1px solid #c4cde0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 10px 10px 10px;
  min-height: 1000px;  /* For demo purpose */
  border: 1px solid #c4cde0; 
}
#content span {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #44619d;
}
```